# Duplicate stdin to stdout

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking for a bash one-liner that duplicates stdin to stdout without interleaving. The only solution I have found so far is to use `tee`, but that does produced interleaved output. What do I mean by this:

If e.g. a file `f` reads

```
a
b
```

I would like to execute

```
cat f | HERE_BE_COMMAND
```

to obtain

```
a
b
a
b
```

If I use `tee -` as the command, the output typically looks something like

```
a
a
b
b
```

Any suggestions for a clean solution?

**Clarification**

The `cat f` command is just an example of where the input can come from. In reality, it is a command that can (should) only be executed once. I also want to refrain from using temporary files, as the processed data is *sort of* sensitive and temporary files are always error-prone when the executed command gets interrupted. Furthermore, I am not interested in a solution that involves additional scripts (as stated above, it should be a *one-liner*) or preparatory commands that need to be executed prior to the actual duplication command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

```
<command_which_produces_output> | { a="$(</dev/stdin)";  echo "$a"; echo "$a"; }
```

In this way, you're saving the content from the standard input in `a` (choose a better name please), and then `echo`'ing twice.

Notice `$(</dev/stdin)` is a similar but more efficient way to do `$(cat /dev/stdin)`.

---

#### Solution 2:

Use `tee` in the following way:

```
<command_which_produces_output> | tee >(echo "$(</dev/stdin)")
```

Here, you're firstly writing to the standard output (that's what `tee` does), and also writing to a FIFO file created by [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
>(echo "$(</dev/stdin)")
```

See for example the file it creates in my system:

```
$ echo >(echo "$(</dev/stdin)")
/dev/fd/63
```

Now, the `echo "$(</dev/stdin)"` part is just the way I found to firstly read the entire file before printing it. It `echo`'es the content read from the process substitution's standard input, but once all the input is read (not like `cat` that prints line by line).

Answer (score 2):

Store the second input in a temp file.

```
cat f | tee /tmp/showlater
cat /tmp/showlater
rm /tmp/showlater
```

Update:
As shown in the comments (@j.a.) the solution above will need to be adjusted into the OP's real needs. Calling will be easier in a function and what do you want to do with errors in your initial commands and in the tee/cat/rm ?

Comment: Maybe if you write it as `tee /tmp/showlater && cat /tmp/showlater && rm /tmp/showlater` makes it more pipeline friendly.

Comment: @j.a. When tee fails (/tmp full), you still want to try to remove the /tmp/showlater file, after showing what was stored in the file. I can't tell what to do with the tmp file when cat fails. The OP can decide what to be, maybe even add `2>&1` before redirecting to `tee` or use `2>/dev/null` for the other commands.

Comment: That's right, anyway my point is that I think the OP needs the solution to be pipeline friendly, so in this case, maybe a function can help: `myf() { tee /tmp/showlater; cat /tmp/showlater; rm /tmp/showlater; }`. Then, you can use it in this way: `cat f | myf`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend `tee /dev/stdout`.

`cat f | tee /dev/stdout`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but a great part of the quality level of the site comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the **why**. While your answer could allow the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. Please explain your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I found is the following `awk` command:

```
awk '{d[NR] = $0} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print d[i]; for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print d[i]}'
```

However, I feel there must be a more "canonical" way of doing this using.

Answer (score 0):

a simple bash script ?
But this will store all the stdin, why not store the output to a file a read the file both if you need ?

```
full=""
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
    full="$full$line\n"
done
printf $full
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to store the output in a file and show it later on. Using `tee` has the advantage of showing the output as it comes:

```
if tmpfile=$(mktemp); then
    commands | tee "$tmpfile"
    cat "$tmpfile"
    rm  "$tmpfile"
else
    echo "Error creating temporary file" >&2
    exit 1     
fi
```

If the amount of output is limited, you can do this:

```
output=$(commands); echo "$output$output"
```